# unable to fetch NSDate from NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, nsdate

I am able to fetch NSString representing the current date and time in PST using the following code.

```
//get current date and time
    NSTimeZone *timeZone = [[NSTimeZone alloc] initWithName:@"America/Los_Angeles"];    
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss zzz"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:timeZone];
    NSLocale *enUSPOSIXLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:enUSPOSIXLocale];
    [enUSPOSIXLocale release];
    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
    NSString *currentDateStr = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    NSLog(@"currentDateStr %@",currentDateStr);
    [dateFormatter release];
```

EDIT:

But the following code to fetch NSDate from NSString doesn't serve my purpose.

```
//get date from string
    NSDateFormatter* formatter2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter2 setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss"];
    NSDate *dt = [[NSDate alloc]init];
    dt = [formatter2 dateFromString:currentDateStr];
    NSLog(@"dt %@",dt);
```

"dt" appears to be null.

Could anybody help me out in solving this issue of getting NSDate from NSString.
Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`NSDateFormatter` also has `dateFromString:` function.

EDIT:

```
//get date from string.
NSDateFormatter* formatter2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[formatter2 setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss zzz"];

NSDate *dt = [formatter2 dateFromString:currentDateStr];
NSLog(@"dt %@",dt);
```

Comment: I am not sure what "zzz" is in your setDateFormat. I removed it and got some output.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of

```
[dateFormatter dateFromString:urString];
```

In your case `urString` is `currentDateStr`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 - (NSString *)datePickerValueChangedd:(UIDatePicker*) datePicker{
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 50, 68, 68)];
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
df.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[df stringFromDate:datePicker.date]];

NSLog(@"I am inside the datePickerValueChanged   - - %@", label.text);
[df release];
globalVariable= label.text;
return (label.text);
}
```